# How do I track and reduce puppeteer data usage?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer script designed to scrape the content of a website.

However, the website requires using expensive residential proxies.

Is there any way to calculate the total amount of data puppeteer would use for a given scraping session?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you'll need to total the bytes of each resource that gets loaded.

You can configure an interceptor to run on each response that will grab the `content-length` header and add up the total bytes:

```
// Enable request/response interception
page.setRequestInterception(true);

let bytesTotal = 0;

page.on('response', response => {
    const headers = response.headers();
    if ('content-length' in headers) {
        const length = parseInt(headers['content-length']);
        bytesTotal += length;
        console.log(bytesTotal);
    }
});

// Let requests continue as normal
page.on('request', request => {
     request.continue();
});
```

As you touched on, scraping with puppeteer can be very expensive. One of the biggest culprits for data usage can be images.

To save data, I recommend you block images from loading.

One method of doing this is by modifying the above request interceptor and preventing image requests:

```
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image') request.abort();
    else request.continue();
});
```

You can see an example of another method for blocking files based on their extension here:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue-cachesafe

Using this approach you can block other resources that may not be necessary such as CSS, or write custom interceptor rules to block certain unecessary/large resources from loading.